# Bootstrap Grid Doesn't Fill Empty Place

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

https://prnt.sc/sa63wm

You can see on the screenshot

How can i fill the empty place with div elements? I tried display:inline-block or the other display things. They didnt work.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap’s grid has excatly 12 column units. Whenever you exceed 12, it will wrap it in a new row. It works, but you should exceed 12 columns in one row.

So instead of doing it above, you should go with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 ... next columns
```

If you want to have them all in row, you should probably use only one row and then put your other content vertically, as your first column is very tall.